# I have some issue during adding VLFEAT to MATLAB 7.10.0 (R2010a)

Tags: matlab, vlfeat

My malab installation folder is

> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\bin\matlab.exe

and I have added `vlfeat` to my current user folder:

> C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\MATLAB\vlfeat-0.9.18\toolbox\vl_setup

I have created a startup file `startup.m` in this location

> C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\MATLAB\startup.m

where I have added a command line

```
run('C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\MATLAB\vlfeat-0.9.18\toolbox\vl_setup')
```

but when I try to use its feature in another `deafautnamefile.m` and use some command like:

```
I = vl_impattern('roofs1') ;
image(I) ;
I = single(rgb2gray(I)) ;
[f,d] = vl_sift(I) ;
```

it gives the following error:

> Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\vlfeat-0.9.18-bin\vlfeat-0.9.18\toolbox\mex\mexw32\vl_sift.mexw32': The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
>
> Error in ==> sf at 4
>   [f,d] = vl_sift(I) ;

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you (re)compile the MEX files when you installed?

Comment: yes I did....will u provide any video regarding to adding vlfeat to matlab.